# Index People Living in New York

Tags: usa, api

My current project involves indexing people from the city of New York. Using various sources and data mining techniques I am supposed to give a confidence rating whether a certain person lives in New York or not.

The problem however is finding public information on people legally. I am able to use Twitter's API to feed tweets from New York to get some names. Further analysis would then be required to determine whether the person is real.Facebook prevents developers from scraping and searching for users. Instagram is a hassle as well.

Do you guys have any suggestions of finding public information on people easily and legally? I don`t need to know where in New York the people live, only that thy live there. Name and Surname is required and any additional information is a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

One approach you might consider is to scrape the [New York White Pages](http://www.whitepages.com/white-pages/new-york-ny). It looks like they have an [API](http://pro.whitepages.com/developer/).